# How to use regular expressions to get specific pieces of a string and putting it in a flatlist (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm getting information from an API. One of those things is a string with multiple dates in it, but the dates are surrounded by a lot of other characters which need to be removed.

I've tried regular expressions to remove the unwanted characters, but I'm totally new to it. this.state.data contains all data from the API and content.rendered contains the string I'm talking about.

The string that I get from the API:

```
"<p>[[&#8220;10 februari&#8221;],[&#8220;17 februari&#8221;],[&#8220;10 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;17 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;24 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;31 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;7 april&#8221;],[&#8220;14 april&#8221;],[&#8220;5 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;12 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;19 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;26 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;2 juni&#8221;],[&#8220;16 juni&#8221;],[&#8220;23 juni&#8221;]]</p>\n"
```

This is the code I'm using to show the data

```
var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;

<FlatList
   data={[this.state.data]}
   renderItem={({item})=>
      <View>
         <Text style={styles.text}>
            content: {t(item, 'content.rendered').safeString.replace(regex, "$1")}   
         </Text>
      </View>
   }/>
```

What I want is it only showing the dates like;
`10 februari, 17 februari, 10 maart, 17 maart, 24 maart, 31 maart, 7 april, 14 april, 5 mei, 12 mei, 19 mei, 26 mei, 2 juni, 16 juni, 23 juni`

But it's showing like;
`<p>[&#8220;10 februari&#8221;,&#8220;17 februari&#8221;,&#8220;10 maart&#8221;,&#8220;17 maart&#8221;,&#8220;24 maart&#8221;,&#8220;31 maart&#8221;,&#8220;7 april&#8221;,&#8220;14 april&#8221;,&#8220;5 mei&#8221;,&#8220;12 mei&#8221;,&#8220;19 mei&#8221;,&#8220;26 mei&#8221;,&#8220;2 juni&#8221;,&#8220;16 juni&#8221;,&#8220;23 juni&#8221;]</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to pass accurate data to flatlist.

So, first you should apply `regex` on your data to get dates only.

you may have to use `var regex = ;(\d{0,2}.[a-zA-Z]+)` to get the dates only from this string. `"<p>[[&#8220;10 februari&#8221;],[&#8220;17 februari&#8221;],[&#8220;10 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;17 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;24 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;31 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;7 april&#8221;],[&#8220;14 april&#8221;],[&#8220;5 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;12 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;19 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;26 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;2 juni&#8221;],[&#8220;16 juni&#8221;],[&#8220;23 juni&#8221;]]</p>\n"`

Have a look at the `Match Information` in SS, you will get the required result in the `first` group. 
[image]

```js
var str = "<p>[[&#8220;10 februari&#8221;],[&#8220;17 februari&#8221;],[&#8220;10 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;17 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;24 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;31 maart&#8221;],[&#8220;7 april&#8221;],[&#8220;14 april&#8221;],[&#8220;5 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;12 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;19 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;26 mei&#8221;],[&#8220;2 juni&#8221;],[&#8220;16 juni&#8221;],[&#8220;23 juni&#8221;]]</p>\n";

function getDates(str) {
 var arr = str.split(',');
 var dates = [];
 arr.forEach(function(e) {
          dates.push(e.match(/;(\d{0,2}.[a-zA-Z]+)/g)[0].replace(';',''));
        });
 return dates;
}

getDates(str);
```

I've wrote a function for you that will give you your required data. Good Luck!

Comment: Do you mean change `var regex = /\[(.*?)\]/g;` into `var regex = /\d{0,2}.[a-zA-Z]+/g` ?

Comment: @raul, I have updated the answer for you. have a look.

Comment: I've changed the var regex to `var regex = /\d{0,2}.[a-zA-Z]+/gm` and replaced the `.replace` with `.match(regex)`. However this gives me an output of `<p10februari17februari10maart(...till) 23juni/p. The <p and /p are still showing this way?

Comment: Raoul, I have added a function for you that will give you the dates after applying regex and replacing character from it.

Comment: Thanks, this puts the dates into a list. I can now use each date separately.

Comment: No Problem! Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex

```
var regex = /("?<p>)?\[*&#\d{4};\]*(<\/p>\n)?/gm
```

Comment: It worked, but it's still showing the <p>  in the beginning, what do I change in the regex to remove it?

Comment: I still had the `$1` in the `replace(regex, "$1")` instead of `replace(regex, "")`. It's working now, thanks!